# How do I make a Sequilize query to get items in a date range agnostic of the year?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a table of dates, of which some are non-recurring and some are annually recurring (with a boolean column to distinguish them).

I want to use Sequilize to get all of the non-recurring and annually recurring items between two dates.

I can easily get the non-recurring items with the below query:

```
    where: {
      date: {
        [op.gte]: startDate,
        [op.lte]: endDate,
      },
      recurring: false,
    },
```

But How can I get the recurring items?

Comment: How does your query return non-recurring elements when it filters on `recurring = true`?

Comment: Ahh, that was a typo

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am going ahead with is to use this query

```
where: {
  date: {
    [op.gte]: moment(startDate).set({year: 2019}).toDate(),
    [op.lte]: moment(endDate).set({year: 2019}).toDate(),
  },
  recurring: true,
},
```

And then make sure when I am inserting into the DB I always use 2019 as the year.